# Can't use keyboard shortcuts when using my Wacom Intuos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet, wacom

So here's my issue: whenever I use my tablet (a Wacom Intuos) I can't use keyboard shortcuts while I'm drawing. In order to use them I have to click out of my artwork (click on the layers panel or tools panel, etc.) and then I'm able to use the shortcuts, but I can't do them smoothly as I draw/edit with my tablet.

How can I fix this?
Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: uninstall the wacom drivers, and reinstall a fresh set, that may help you out

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's a known issue with Wacom tablets and Photoshop shortcuts becoming unresponsive. Give this plugin from Adobe a try: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-menus-turn-white-mac.html

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of this issue.